# First and second derivative of a summation function C(S)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, summation

I have the following C(S) function and I would like to learn how to calculate the first and second derivatives

[C(S) function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceiMN.png)

I need to prove that C(S) function is convex for all S, thus that the second derivative >= 0.
Therefore I would like your help with the first and second derivative of this function.
The second part (black) I think I managed to calculate and becomes 0.
The first part (red) I do not know how to do calculate this, because of the double summation.

Comment: Your function definition suggests that $S$ can only take integer values, in which case the derivative doesn’t make sense.

Comment: Can you please explain Tavish? I was told to look whether C(S+2)-2C(S+1)+C(S)>0.

Comment: The summation bounds ( $S$ and $S+1$) can only be integers. If the definition you gave is correct, then $S$ can only be an integer so you can’t calculate the derivative. As for that inequality, have you tried simplifying the LHS?

Comment: @tavish, yes I have tried, but so far I am not able.. To me it seems like it's becoming more and more complex. 
When I fill the equation in numerically, it holds. But I am not able to write it down using simplification